# how to add translation to my store

Tags: magento2

I need to translate my storefront. I already have **`ar_SA.csv`** file in **`i18n folder`** in my templatemonster theme folder

How to add translation to my store?

Answer (score 0):

The process of translating a string is very simple in Magento.

You can translate all text which is written in files through translation CSV file or inline translation process.

Below is the process using the translation file.

You need to write the string and its translation in the following manner in your translation CSV file:

```
"text to translate", "translated text"
```

If the text to be translated has some complex part, like HTML tags or number etc., then it can be kept intact. For example:

```
"Welcome to %store_name","store_name% مرحبا بك في"
```

If you want to translate the content of the product, category, page, static block or blog post etc., you need to choose the store from the stores' scope and write the content in the specific language.

I hope, it's clear now.